# "Invalid JSON string: response too large"

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a Google Sheets document that gets its data from a BigQuery result set. Following some changes in the query, I am now getting:

> Invalid JSON string: response too large

on the line executing the call:

```
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
```

I guess this simply means that the result set is too large for Google Sheets to handle but I need this data in the sheet (there's no way I can omit some of it) and I can't split this to more than one sheet (it won't make sense reading this data in parts and my clients won't like it).

Any ideas on how to solve / get around this?

Comment: you cant make it receive a response that large. either make many jobs or figure a way to reduce the response size, maybe some fields (columns) can be filtered out with the request parameters. you can also make one query per column which will be cheaper in bigquery that paging by rows

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i use variations of substitute/replace or regexreplace functions to either omit redundant, useless data before it is parsed, thus reducing the size, or sometimes, you can use regexreplace to stick delimiters in, then split the data to reduce it to a reasonable size. It really depends on the type of data your trying to pull in.